# read json file from zip with adm-zip

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, adm-zip

Im trying to read a zip file and then parse a json file at the root of the zip.

The json file is called manifest.json and will be called this in every zip file i read.

Currently i have the following function

```
function getFileContents(directory){
    // reading archives
    var zip = new AdmZip(directory);
    var zipEntries = zip.getEntries(); // an array of ZipEntry records

    zipEntries.forEach(function (zipEntry) {
        if (zipEntry.entryName == "manifest.json") {
            console.log('getData', zipEntry.getData());
            console.log('data',zipEntry.data.toString('utf8')); 
        }
    });
}
```

However i get the following exception in the console

```
getData <Buffer ff fe 7b 00 0a 00 20 00 20 00 22 00 62 00 75 00 69 00 6c 00 64 0
0 22 00 3a 00 20 00 22 00 34 00 2e 00 38 00 2e 00 37 00 32 00 31 00 39 00 22 00
2c 00 0a ...>

TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined
    at c:\direc\Custom_Modules\readZipFileModule\readZipFileModule.js:18:46
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

Of the back of this ive tried:

```
function getFileContents(directory){
    // reading archives
    var zip = new AdmZip(directory);
    var zipEntries = zip.getEntries(); // an array of ZipEntry records

    zipEntries.forEach(function (zipEntry) {
        if (zipEntry.entryName == "manifest.json") { 
            var decompressedData = zip.readFile(zipEntry);
            var data = zip.readAsText(zipEntry)
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        }
    });
}
```

if i console.log data i get:

```
??{
     " b u i l d " :   " 4 . 8 . 7 2 1 9 " ,
     " b r a n c h " :   " s t e p h e n " ,
     " t i m e s t a m p " :   " 1 5 - 0 1 - 2 0 1 4   0 9 : 0 6 : 2 7 "
 }
```

That is the correct data from the file however there are not spaces inbetween every character.
But when i try and parse it it obviously throws an error about '??' Where are the question marks coming from? I don't fully understand how to use adm-zip correctly what exactly am i doing wrong to read a json file from a zip in nodejs? It doesn't need to save the file just parse its data into an object.

Thanks for any and all assistance with this.

Comment: "??" seems that the expected request was a **jsonp** and the real response is a simple **JSON** (before `JSON.parse(data)` seems there has been already a parsing)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is too late... but I was having the same problem. You can use `zipEntry.getData().toString('utf8')`

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem.

It was the way a power shell script was making the json file and then writing it to a script.

Im afraid i don't have any more information than that as i didn't write the original power shell script nor the modified version.